# magento force the excution of cron job before time

Tags: magento

I have configured cron job for every 10'

I also added it to crontab as it recomended by Magento. It works well!

Is there a way to manually execute this job without waiting this 10' (force it) for testing purpose, without changing the config.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Aoe Scheduler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html) extension for it. Another option is use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#run-cronjob).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cron timings in Magento's configuration in the admin panel. I believe it's under "System". Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Please read carefully my question, I don't want to edit the config.xml. thank you anyway.